# How to use custom repository methods in Twig template?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Assuming I have an entity `User` and an entity `Book` and they're both joined by `User.bookId = Book.id` (this marks a user owns a certain book, relation type oneUserToManyBook).

If I now want to execute a performance friendly fetch with Doctrine's DQL or QueryBuilder for all `Books` a `User` has read, what is the best way to implement this in a Symfony2/Doctrine2 webapp, so that I can use them in my `User` loop in a Twig template?

### Twig

```
{% for user in users %}
   {{ user.name|e }}
       {% for address in user.getAddressesByUserId(user.getId()) %}
           {{ address.city }}
       {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

I see two approaches, but both don't lead to my target:

### 1st approach

Create a custom repository class `BookRepository`:

```
public function getBooksOwnedByUser($user_id) {
    return $em->createQuery('SELECT b.title
                             FROM MyBundle\Entity\User u,
                                  MyBundle\Entity\Book b
                             WHERE u.book_id = b.id'
                             AND u.id = :user_id)
              ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
              ->getResult();
}
```

**Problem**: Works fine, but I cant call `getBooksOwnedByUser()` in my Twig template (because it's not tied to the entity `User`, but to it's repository, which is a subclass of `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`.

---

### 2nd approach

Execute the same query as above - not in my `UserRepository`, but directly in my `User` entity class.

**Problem here:** I could call this method in my Twig template, but I cannot (and should not) use the `EntityManager` in my `User` entity class.

Comment: 3rd approach: Do this from the controller and send the data to the view?

Comment: Well wouldn't that mean I would have to loop over all users before I render? Isn't there a sleeker way? But I like the general feasibility of your approach! +1

Comment: Well yes, but even if you do it in the view, you would have to loop over all the users :)

Comment: Yeah that's true. I implemented it the way you suggested. But I'll still have to loop in my template, won't I? :-)

Comment: Yes, you will have to loop over your `users` but that's ok, the view can do this. What it shouldn't do is retrieve information from the database (because this is business logic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best if you make a relationship from User to Books. Assuming you have made this relationship you can make your query like this:

```
public function getBooksOwnedByUser($user_id) {
    return $em->createQuery('SELECT u, b
                            FROM MyBundle\Entity\User u
                            JOIN u.books b
                            WHERE  u.id = :user_id')
                        ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
                        ->getResult();
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user_with_books = $em->getRepository('MyBundle\Entity\User')
    ->getBooksOwnedByUser($user->getId());

return $this->render('YourTemplate.html.twig', array(
        'user_with_books' => $user_with_books,
));
```

In twig:

```
{% for book in user.books %}
    {{ book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Some considerations:

1. For multiple users you will have to change the query (lazy loading is possible but not advised).
2. If it's a lot of data you can get a performance boost by getting a scalar result (Array)
3. If you need different queries for the user that can not be combined you will have to store different variables (objects or arrays). That's why I named it "user_with_books". But if you only have this user in your template you can just as well call it "user".
4. `user.getAddressesByUserId(user.getId())` <-- passing data from one model to query is the responsiblity of the controller (or a service). Best practice is to avoid doing this in your template.

So the answer:
You can not do anything with a custom repository method because it's a function. A function on itself doesn't represent any data. So this is a way you can retrieve the actual data **with** that function and display that.