# Repository with symfony2 and Doctrine not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository

I'm trying to work with Entity Repository to write my custom functions.

I have an Entity and his Repository generated from yaml file

**Yaml file**

```
Bluesys\WeekupBundle\Entity\Event:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: Bluesys\WeekupBundle\Repository\Event
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  ...
```

**Entity code automatically generated**

```
namespace Bluesys\WeekupBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Event
*/
class Event
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    */
    private $id;

    ...

}
```

**Repository code automatically generated**
I juste wrote the function isHidden

```
namespace Bluesys\WeekupBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * Event
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class Event extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * isHidden
     *
     * @return bool  
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
       return true;
    }
}
```

**The Controller code**

```
namespace Bluesys\WeekupBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Bluesys\WeekupBundle\Event\Event;

...

class TimelineController extends Controller
{

    public function testAction(){

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('BluesysWeekupBundle:Event');
        $event = $repository->findOneById( 73 );

        return $this->render('BluesysWeekupBundle::test.html.twig', array( 'event' => $event ));
    }

    ...
```

**And the view code**

```
{{ event.isHidden }}
```

**I get this error :** 
Method "isHidden" for object "Bluesys\WeekupBundle\Entity\Event" does not exist in BluesysWeekupBundle::test.html.twig at line 1

Can somebody help me by telling me what is missing ?

Comment: Can you try this `event.id` for example into your twig, just to see if it's about event or from the repository methods

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277211/how-to-use-custom-repository-methods-in-twig-template

Comment: You shouldn't call repo function . Thats business logic, that should not appear in templates.

Comment: Yes, event.id is working! I think my problem is due to that The Entity is instantiate, but not the repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repository classes are used only for selecting/fetching data. They are not the part of entity/object.
If you really want to call `isHidden` method by repository you can acheive this by passing the whole repository to template (`return $this->render('BluesysWeekupBundle::test.html.twig', array( 'event' => $repository ));`), but this is very bad idea.

Instead you can put `isHidden()` method into your entity class and call it as `event.isHidden`..

Comment: Thanks... and can I write some queries in the method isHidden?

Comment: @Ced Of course you can write. The query should return the array of objects, single object, partial object or some fields of entity as array result..

Comment: I read in this article that getDoctrine() should not be used in Entity classes. Also, I can not access EntityManager from Entity Class. [getDoctrine() in Entity article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/2o9ysz-fk7o)

Comment: @Ced You don't need to use entityManager in entity classes. If your `isHidden()` method returns single boolean value simply put it in entity class. If it performs some heavy logic, use services, twig extensions, controllers...

Comment: It's only for the example. This method will return data from model (DQL)

Comment: @Ced Repository classes are not entity classes, you can not use it like `$entity->someMethod()` or `{{ entity.someMethod }}`